# Eclipse RCP - How to use a local context to solve dependencies when using @Inject

Tags: java, eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp

I am working on an application that was developed using Eclipse RCP 3, and right now we are trying to add dependency injection (so..some Eclipse RCP 4 features) to our client code.

We managed to populate the top level of the context with the services that we need that must be present in the entire applicaiton (I assume this is the so called Application context).

Since our app can have multiple view (even of the same type), we need to use some local contexts for this (..some scope mechanism). This local context, we intend to contain instances common to a view instance, and is also liked to its parent context (the Application context that contains the services)...so basically we managed to obtain this hierarchy.

Let's throw in some code :)

```
@Inject  //Constructor
public MyViewPart(final IEclipseContext parentContext) {
  localContext.setParent(parentContext);

  myModel = ContextInjectionFactory.make(MyModel.class, localContext);
  localContext.set(MyModel.class, myModel);

  classThatNeedAModel = ContextInjectionFactory.make(ClassThatNeedAModel.class, localContext);


  localContext.activateBranch();
  // we have a mechanism that activated the localContext based on the active 
  // part, that works as expected, so I just activate the localContext here.
}
```

Creating an instance like this, works like a charm, classThatNeedAModel gets the model injected in it..

However, we want a way to avoid using all this calls to

> make

method...Instead, we want something like this :

```
@Inject
public void set(final ClassThatNeedAModel classThatNeedAModel) {
  this.classThatNeedAModel = classThatNeedAModel;
}
```

So in the constructor I could initialize the localContext and activate it, and from then on, I would like the framework to somehow use the active localContext, and not the Application context (that contains just the services, and not my model, because this will cause a null to be injected).

Is there any way to achieve this? Can we somehow control which context is used to solve the dependencies that an injection needs?

Thanks!

Comment: Each MPart (view, editor etc.) has its own separate context already

Comment: @greg-449 Since the app was built with RCP 3.0, we don't use MPart...instead, we use the old "ViewPart"

Comment: Makes no difference. The 3.x compatibility code creates an MPart for your ViewPart.

Comment: @greg-449 do you think you could details this a little bit? :)  Like how does "The 3.x compatibility code creates an MPart for your ViewPart" help me, and how could I use the separate context that you said that is created by the framework

Comment: I believe that the context injected in to your constructor is the view instance specific context from the MPart. But I don't use 3.x views like this so you will have to check that.

Comment: @greg-449 Just looked into this again, and it seems like it is not..I opened 2 separate views, and in the constructor I got the same IEclipseContext instance (since the hashCode was the same in both cases)...So it is like I assumed, this is just the highest level context, the one that for my app, contains the services...So it is the Application Context, not the view specific one :(